# Is this limit finite, or infinite?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, optimization

Is
$$\lim_{x\uparrow 1}\left(\frac{1-x}{x}\max\{nx^n|n\in\mathbb{N}\} \right)$$
infinite, or finite? ($\mathbb{N}$ is the set of the natural numbers).
According to Mathematica, it looks like converging to between 0.3 and 0.4...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean with $\max_{n\geq 1} nx^n$

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it means for each x, we choose n to maximize it.

Comment: @vrugtehagel, it makes sense if you're taking the limit from the left, $x\to0^-$.

Comment: I edited, I hope it became clearer! :)

Comment: So are we taking the limit $x\to 0$ or $x\to 1$ now?

Comment: @vrugtehagel, sorry, I meant to say $x\to1^-$, not $0^-$.

Comment: And we're approaching $x$ from the bottom right? I mean, if $x>1$, then the maximum of $nx^n$ does not exist (is infinite)

Comment: Where did this limit come from?

Comment: It should be between $.3$ and $.4$ in the question instead of $3$ and $4$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. One may observe that, for $0<x<1$, we have
$$
\max_{n\in\mathbb{N}} n x^n \sim  
\dfrac{e^{-1}}{-\ln x} \tag1
$$ We obtain $(1)$ by differentiating
$$
n \mapsto n x^n, 
$$ and by seeing where the derivative
$$
n \mapsto (1+n \ln x)\:x^n
$$  vanishes.

Then

> $$
> \lim_{x\to 1^-}\Big(\frac{1-x}{x}\max_{n\in\mathbb{N}} n x^n\Big)=\lim_{x\to 1^-}\Big(\frac{1-x}{x}\dfrac{e^{-1}}{-\ln x}\Big)=e^{-1}\tag2
> $$

since
$$
\lim_{x\to 1^-}\Big(\frac{1-x}{-\ln x}\Big)=1.
$$

Comment: I get $e^{-1}$, not $e$.

Comment: This seems false. First of all, testing the first equality $(1)$ for $x=0.99$ and $x=0.999$ does not support it; also, as the OP noted, the limit should be somewhere between $3$ and $4$, so $e$ seems false

Comment: @BarryCipra Typo edited. Thanks!

Comment: @vrugtehagel, $e^{-1}$ is even further from what the OP got!

Comment: @vrugtehagel I consider your point of view, but please, I don't see my mistake.

Comment: Well, perhaps I was wrong. Further testing supports your final answer $e^{-1}$. Not sure where I went wrong on equation $(1)$, but well, I believe you now

Comment: @vrugtehagel Thank you.

Comment: A minor detail that doesn't change the answer: the supremum in (1) is over the natural numbers only, so the equation (1) is only approximately correct.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland Good catch! It does not change the answer. Thanks.